# Check if all array elements are set

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$my_array = array ( 
                 'city'     => $this->input->post('city'),
                 'country'  => $this->input->post('country'),
                 'state'    => $this->input->post('state'),
                 'miles'    => $this->input->post('miles')
                 );
```

Which **short** php function or method can I use to check if all array items are set? Right now I'm using the following code

```
$my_array = array_filter($my_array);

if (!empty($my_array['city']) && !empty($my_array[['miles']) && !empty($my_array[['state']) && !empty($my_array['country']))
{
     //do something
}
```

note: I'm using the `array_filter()` function to remove all entries from a query that equal  FALSE.

Comment: You code, as it is now, is redundant as `empty()` and the default behavior of `array_filter()` are *virtually* identical. Elaborate on *items are set*.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, thanks for the info! I tried using just `if $my_array` but there will always be at least one element set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you can just `count` the number of elements left after filtering:

```
if(count($my_array) == 4){
    // all 4 still set
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer but depending on the context it might not work properly since count() returns the number of elements in an array and I could have an array with exactly four elements but different keys. The method provided by @deceze is therefore more suitable for a general situation.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can do this:

```
$required = array_flip(array('city', 'country', 'state', 'miles'));
if (array_diff_key($required, $my_array)) {
    // not all keys are set
}
```

In this specific case though, counting the resulting array should indeed be enough.

Answer (score 1):

In that case? I'd just test `count(array_values($my_array)) == 4`.

Comment: thanks! `count(array_values)` seems precise but would a value exists without a key? I'm just trying to decide whether to count the entire array or just values.

Comment: @Cyber No, all values must have a key, and all keys must have values (even if it's `null`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function testArray($array) { 
 for($x = 0,$len = count($array); $x < $len; $x++) {
     if(empty($array[$x])) {
          return false; 
      }
  }
         return true; 
}
```

short function:

```
count(array_map('empty', $array)) == count($array)
```

Comment: Thanks but the goal is to have a shorter function than mine.